# VueJS images from json won´t render

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I´ve got a JSON file like this:

```
"images": {
      "thumbnail": "./assets/starry-night/thumbnail.jpg",
      "hero": {
        "small": "./assets/starry-night/hero-small.jpg",
        "large": "./assets/starry-night/hero-large.jpg"
      },
      "gallery": "./assets/starry-night/gallery.jpg"
    }
```

My code in Vue is:

```
<img
          v-bind:src="data.images.thumbnail"
          alt=""
          srcset=""
          height="100px"
          width="100px"
        />
```

And it "works", it gives back an IMG. But the path of the image is ./assets/starry-night/gallery.jpg and I think that´s why it won´t load.

Do I have to trick the router or anything?

```
./assets/starry-night/gallery.jpg
```

Output in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Your data is treated as a string, therefore it's looking for the path which of course doesn't exists.
Just define a `const publicUrl = 'http://mysite.test/'` somewhere to complete the image URL such as

```
<img
    v-bind:src="publicUrl + data.images.thumbnail"
    alt=""
    srcset=""
    height="100px"
    width="100px"
/>
```

In addition, you can reference a folder by doing

```
<img src="@/assets/starry-night/thumbnail.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Thank you @Luciano. Actually that´s what I thought but i didn´t know how to solve it :) However, it doesn´t work either: <img src="undefined./assets/starry-night/thumbnail.jpg" alt="" srcset="undefined undefined" height="100px" width="100px">

Answer (score 0):

Solved with:

```
 created() {
    this.publicURL = "https://6e222.csb.app";
  },
```

And moved assets/xxx/ to PUBLIC folder instead of in SRC.